AppLifeCycleState.detached is not called When App is closed

  Future<void> onAppClose({required String userId}) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(FirebaseConstants.usersCollection)
        .doc(userId)
        .update({'isOnline': false});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    final userId = ref.read(currentDeliveryUserProvider)?.reference.id;
    print("state--------------------$state");
    if (userId != null) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
        // The app is completely closing
        onAppClose(userId: userId);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'ONtrend Partners',
        home: const SplashScreen(),
        // home:   TestFile(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.dmSansTextTheme(),
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'm building a delivery app in Flutter, and I'm trying to set the user's isOnline status to false in Firebase when the app is closed. I've been using WidgetsBindingObserver to listen for AppLifecycleState changes, and everything works fine for AppLifeCycleState.paused and AppLifeCycleState.inactive. However, I noticed that AppLifeCycleState.detached is not being triggered when the app is completely closed (terminated).

If the user swipes the app away in the app switcher (I think that is what you mean with "completely closed (terminated)") then the OS kills the app without giving any heads-up to the app itself, and there is therefore no way to detect that. If the OS suspends or stops the app as part of its normal resource management processes (e.g. when the app has not been in the foreground for a while) then you should receive the life cycle state updates.
